# Exceptions for http status codes

Tags: c#, exception, http-error

Are there any built-in or libraries for http exceptions provided in C#?

For instance from Java, they have all for 400 and 500 errors. They have provided bunch of these exceptions so you can throw in your code.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ClientErrorException.html

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
```

**Use Case:**

It helps a lot to compare what kind of exception was thrown in the "Controller" and then respond accordingly in the "View" tier, for instance I've different kinds of custom responses as per the required contract for each kind of the exceptions.

Wondering if there are 3rd party open source libraries or built-in custom types to compare against in C#.

**Edit**

Still not success. Came across something close at this [URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx) but unable to get it working on .NET core, I think it's available on .net standard something? I'm on a mac running .net core.

I think I'll end up creating my own custom HttpException class with status code as int field.

Comment: using a try catch block you can trap specific exceptions, webexceptions, soapexceptions, interpret the status code and handle it accordingly.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm running .net core, any idea why I can't see HttpException in system.Web namespace?

Comment: I recommend to not think in Java while writing C#. What's the great difference in having n specific Exception Types or one Exception Type and switching on Status Code ... not so much, apart from personal taste, imho.

Comment: yes i understand, it's not java vs. c#, it's common stuff and looking for typed exceptions, that's all or something that allows to work with enums, codes etc.

Comment: @AshleyMedway the link you referenced seems promising, the only problem is that I can't see it in the code hints. I'm running .net core on the mac and it's an ASP.NET CORE empty project.

Comment: You may have to add a reference in the project to get the intellisense.

Comment: @Fildor not sure but I've imported the `System.Web` namespace but nothing. Also i found few types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.badrequestresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0 is it what I'm looking for?

Comment: Looks promising at least. But I'm not too deep into that.

Comment: I liked more `System.Web.HttpException`, you could construct the `int32` and throw, and in the "view" part I can use switch for against different codes for respective responses, the only problem is .net core doesn't have access to this namespace, where should I look into to resolve this?

Comment: nothing so far, it seems i've to create my custom exception class with an int status code.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, your controller can return any status code you like.

For example:

```
public IActionResult MyApi()
{
    return NotFound()
}
```

There are some defined (OK(), NotFound()) and you can also make up your own:

```
public IActionResult MyApi()
{
    return StatusCode(401);
}
```

Comment: is there a namespace or reference document?

Comment: just wanted to share that it's a custom MVC framework, not using any specific asp.net controller. I meant controller in general sense of mvc.